# Is it safe to expect .NET DialogResult enum values to correspond to their VBScript MsgBox equivalents?

Tags: .net, vbscript, enums

I'm using .NET to write a COM+ control that will provide a custom collection of dialog boxes for advanced debugging output in VBScripts. One of the methods of the control is designed to exactly mimic the signature of the standard VBScript MsgBox function, so a simple find/replace can easily upgrade all instances of MsgBox in existing code with an enhanced dialog.

After doing some quick tests, I've found that the underling integer values of .NET's System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult enum directly correspond to their VBScript counterparts. (I.e. DialogResult.OK == vbOK, DialogResult.Abort == vbAbort, etc.)

If this always holds true, then that greatly simplifies the task of translating the return value from a .NET form back into an appropriate value for my MsgBox replacement function to return. (I need only do a simple typecast rather than any kind of lookup function.)

Unfortunately, while the [MSDN documentation for VBScript's MsgBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is quite explicit in what numerical values the function returns, the [documentation for DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) is silent on what the enum's underlying values are.

While it makes sense that Microsoft would keep the two sets of constants the same, I'd hate to rely on an undocumented feature and get the rug pulled out from under me down the road, so can anyone tell me if the values of DialogResult are documented anywhere and if it is safe to make the assumption that they will likely remain unchanged in a future version of .NET?